# Is there a gadget or other way to display the wallpaper file name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, slideshow

I have my wallpaper set to SlideShow from my Pictures folder.  Sometimes, I'd like to know which picture I'm looking at.  Is there a gadget or other way to display the wallpaper file name in Windows 7?

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a script](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-background-file-location-right-click-menu-windows-7/) (with installation picture) that will allow you to check the name of the current image.

This script adds a Desktop Background File Location to the context menu in Windows 7 so that you can see what file is being shown in the slideshow.  Here are the instructions for the script. Please check out [this page](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/desktop-background-file-location-right-click-menu-windows-7/) for further details.

> 1. Download [WPTargetDir.zip](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/h1-10/WPTargetDir.zip), unzip and extract the contents to a
>      folder.
> 2. Move the file WPTargetDir.vbs to the Windows directory.
> 3. Double-click Add.reg to add the context menu option.
> 4. Hold the SHIFT key down and right-click on an empty area in the
>      Desktop. You’ll see the Desktop
>      Background File Location option.
>
> [image: image 1]
>
> Selecting this option gets the current
>   wallpaper file name from the registry,
>   opens the target folder and selects
>   the image file.
>
> To remove/uninstall this option, run
>   the file undo.reg, and then manually
>   delete WPTargetDir.vbs manually from
>   the Windows folder.

Comment: The site is down or incredibly slow for me, maybe you could add a quick howto here on SU.

Comment: Done.  Weird about the site.  Is there an issue in copying his content.  the dude did a good job and might like the traffic to his site.

Comment: Of course he deserves traffic. You *might* want to rewrite it, as just plain copying isn't the best thing to do here on SU (they obviously don't want to get into legal issues as all content is made publicly available). I made it a quote in the meantime.